# Class to recognize Port from string

Tags: c#, string, url

I have a method that get's urls in different varations like

> foo.bar.com:5678

I need to get the port out of this like

```
System.Uri foo = new Uri("foo.bar.com:5678");
int port = foo.Port;
```

but it always returns `-1` instead of `5678`

Comment: That's not a valid value for the Uri class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri - you need to specify the protocol

Comment: you should have protocol in you URI string.

Answer (score 1):

Prepend a protocol to the string or split it yourself using a custom method:

```
static readonly char[] s_splitter = new char[1] { ':' };
static int GetPort(string s)
{
    int port = -1;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return port;

    string[] parts = s.Split(s_splitter);
    if (parts.Length == 2)
        int.TryParse(parts[1], out port);
    return port;
}
```

If you are using .NET Core or the [System.Memory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Memory/) NuGet package, you could retrieve the port without allocating any additional strings:

```
static int GetPort(string s)
{
    int port = -1;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return port;

    ReadOnlySpan<char> span = s;
    int index = span.IndexOf(':');
    if (index == -1 || s.Length < index)
        return port;

    int.TryParse(span.Slice(index + 1), out port);
    return port;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the `port` from URI, its required that URI have `protocol`

https://rextester.com/TRDAKO93228

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       System.Uri foo1 = new Uri("foo.bar.com:5678");
        int port1 = foo1.Port;  // it will return -1 as no protocol specified.
        System.Uri foo2 = new Uri("http://foo.bar.com:5678");
        int port2 = foo2.Port;  // it will return 5678
        System.Uri foo3 = new Uri("ftp://foo.bar.com:5678");
        int port3 = foo3.Port;  // it will return 5678
        System.Uri foo4 = new Uri("https://foo.bar.com");
        int port4 = foo4.Port;  // it will return 443 - default for HTTPS
        Console.WriteLine(port1);
        Console.WriteLine(port2);
        Console.WriteLine(port3);
        Console.WriteLine(port4);
    }
}
```

if you have simple string that doesn't have protocol, you can prepend `http://` OR `ftp://` or others, but remember if you prepended protocol and if your URI doesn't have port, it will return default port for that protocol.(Notice port4)